# Setting Next.js Image placeholder default to blur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

The Next.js `Image` component provides a `placeholder` property to set what to display while the image is loading. Its possible values are `blur` or `empty`, and the default value is `empty`. This means that for each image that should have a blurred placeholder, we must individually set `placeholder="blur"`, as follows:

```
<Image
  src={profilePic}
  alt="Picture of the author"
  placeholder="blur"
/>
```

Since almost all images on my site are to have a blurred placeholder, I would like to configure my Next.js site to change the default value of `placeholder` to `blur` rather than `empty`, and spare some lines of code. **How can we change the default value for `placeholder`?**

(And if this is something that should rather not be done, why?)

Comment: Hi mbaytas! Have you checked my below answer? Let me know please!

Answer (score 1):

Next.js doesn't provide a way to modify the [`placeholder`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#placeholder) globally as it does for [`unoptimized`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized) property, for example.

A solution is to create a wrapper, which is quite a common way to customize external library element behaviors across a codebase:

```js
// components/Image.js

import NextImage from "next/image";

export default function Image(props) {
  return <NextImage placeholder="blur" {...props} />;
}
```

This way, in other palaces, you import the above component instead of importing directly `next/image`. As an example:

```js
// pages/index.js

import Image from "../components/Image";

export default function Page() {
  return <Image src={profilePic} alt="Picture of the author" />;
}
```